# redirecting system call output in python

Tags: python, redirect, pipe, system-calls

I wish to execute os.system('ls') in python. the return value of this statement is an error code integer..but I want to  get the contents of the present directory as a string. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

[`os.listdir(".")`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir)

---

In general, if you want to call a function and get the arguments, you should use [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). But a lot of the basic directory stuff is in the `os` module so you don't have to do that.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` invokes programs and doesn't call functions. Regardless, it would allow you to capture its output, but Python's `os.listdir()` would be the better way to accomplish specifically what the OP wants to do (as stated).

Answer (score 0):

Python as build-in functionality like os.listdir() or os.walk() for listing stuff
on the filesystem. Running 'ls' yourself is very bad-style. In general look at the documentation of the subprocess module giving you all flexibility for interacting with external commands.